# How to make inter-database queries with dynamic SQL Server database name?

Tags: sql-server-2005, instance

We have two database servers with SQL Server 2005, with two databases each. The secondary server have two SQL Server instances: one for development and other for reporting. Both instances on secondary server restore backups daily from the primary server, but only the development instance could have data modifications.

- The two databases are from different applications, but one database has triggers that alter data on the other database. Triggers update the second database hardcoding its name, like `UPDATE database2..thetable`
- One database can fetch data from another via SQL queries from one application or Stored Procedures, hardcoded as `SELECT FROM database2..thetable`

We are considering joining the two SQL Server instances on secondary server (reporting and development) to simplify administration and memory managing, but I couldn't find a solution to make triggers and stored procedures calls another database dynamically and automatically with another name using the same suffix. Ex:

- Instance: RS

  - DB1 (calls DB2 with DB2..table)
  - DB2
- Instance: DEV

  - DB1 (calls DB2 with DB2..table)
  - DB2

Into:

- Instance: default

  - DB1_RS (calls DB2_RS with DB2_RS..table)
  - DB2_RS
  - DB1_DEV (calls DB2_DEV with DB2_DEV..table)
  - DB2_DEV

What are the possible solutions to this? I can think about some, but they are too convoluted:

- Create dynamically T-SQL to be executed via EXEC(). This makes thing more complex because the triggers have lots of code for UPDATES and INSERTS and DELETES.
- Create separate triggers and stored procedures for each group of database names (one for DB1, other for DB1_DEV, other for DB1_RS). This approach seems to not scale...
- Make the database name dynamic on the query: `INSERT INTO @db..table`. Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support this... :-(

Is there a simpler and effective solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand all of the variables but I suspect you would be able to use synonyms that are different between the two environments which would allow the code to be the same. It is a layer of abstraction that requires documentation and/or an extra layer of the onion to peel, but can definitely simplify the code you write. Here is the [CREATE SYNONYM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) topic... I have used them extensively so please let me know if you have further questions about them.

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your response! This is the solution I was looking for! I like this abstraction layer, and the synonyms can be dropped/created automatically by our restore scripts when databases are restored for testing, development, reporting, etc. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)? Linked servers help you to treat remote SQL server/DB as a local server/DB. You can create a linked server, and once you consolidate the DBs (on the same server) you can either change your linked server configuration, or use three part naming conventions for the DBs.